# How to prove absolute convergence by using the alternating series test?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

From what I gather, I can use the alternating series test to check if an alternating series converges or diverges.
Let's say, for example I have the series of $(-1)^k\sin (\frac{1}{k})$.
I've proved that the series converges with the limit of sin which is equal to $0$, and $f(x)$ of $\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ is a decreasing function.

Now, how can I prove that it is an absolute convergence?
Didn't I just prove that as well by taking the alternating part i.e. $(-1)$ and removing it from the series/taking the absolute value of it?

Comment: The alternating series test doesn't help to prove absolute converges. You need to show that the series of absolute values $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n|$ converges.

Comment: If we take $a_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$, the series $a_1+a_2+\cdots$ converges , but not absolutely.

Comment: @Mark
But by taking the absolute value of an I can eliminate (-1)^n. I also did this by using the alternating series test. 

Do I need to take another test for example integral or ratio to prove absolute convergence?

Comment: Alternating series already converge , if the absolute values form a decreasing null-sequence. This is not sufficient for absolute convergence. You need stronger tests.

Answer (score 1):

If a series of positive terms converges, the corresponding alternating series will converge. The converse is not true.